# Ski resort's lifts status and trains length API

Tags: api, ski

Im looking for API that contains Europe's ski resorts data that include lifts and trails status, max/min altitude, ski pass information etc.

this is the closest thing that i have found:

> http://docs.clientservice.onthesnow.com/docs/index.html

but they are not responding to my emails so can't create an account and get access.